# How do I set a default query string in my URL?

Tags: php, javascript, url, url-rewriting, web-deployment

I am trying to build a webapp which shall filter results based on the users current button select and slider choice, I will be achieving this via PHP, SQL and AJAX calls but I need help with sending the correct data to my URL.

DB Dip -

```
$pType = $_GET['s'];

$fPsiVal = '15000';
$fGpmVal = '10000';
$hPsiVal = '30000';
$hGpmVal = '10000';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM pumps 
        WHERE pump_type =  '$pType'
        AND flow_psi   <=  '$fPsiVal'
        AND flow_gpm   <=  '$fGpmVal'
        AND high_psi   <=  '$hPsiVal'
        AND high_gpm   <=  '$hGpmVal'";
```

I want to set a default value for pType of ?pType=CONTINUOUS instead of having a static variable, how would I pass this to my URL when the page is called initially?

In order to handle user result filtering I created a form with the method of GET which as I currently understand should send the data to the URL upon for submission, however nothing happens and I am not quite sure what I have done wrong

GET Form -

```
 <form name="pumpCat" action="?s=<?php echo $pType ?>" method="get" align="center">
     <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
          <button type="submit" class="<?php if( $pType == 'intermittent' ){ echo 'active '; } else echo 'noClass '; ?>btn btn-primary waitingUiBut" id="but1" name="s" value="intermittent" action="pumpCat">INTERMITTENT</button>
          <button type="submit" class="<?php if( $pType == 'continuous' ){ echo 'active '; } else echo 'noClass '; ?>btn btn-primary waitingUiBut" id="but4" name="s" value="continuous"action="pumpCat">CONTINUOUS</button>  
      </div>
 </form>
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "I want to set a default value for pType of ?pType=CONTINUOUS instead of having a static variable" ?

Comment: When the page loads initially the URL shows testsite.com/page.php? a user then has to click on a toggle button to get force the URL to change to testsite.com/page.php?p=XYZ.

What I want to do is have testsite.com/page.php?p=XYZ be the URL on the initial page load if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this problem I simply added a query string on the navbar link

```
<li class=" animateNav <?php if ($pageCat == "Well Service"){ echo "active"; } ?>"><a id="link" href="wellservice.php?s=intermittent">WELL SERVICE</a></li>
```

and also amended the forms using GET to change the query parameters on the buttons onclick event

```
            <form name="pumpType" action="?s=<?php echo $pType ?>" method="get" align="center">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
              <button type="submit" class="<?php if( $pType == 'intermittent' ){ echo 'active '; } ?>btn btn-primary waitingUiBut" id="but1" name="s" value="intermittent" action="pumpCat">INTERMITTENT</button>
              <button type="submit" class="<?php if( $pType == 'continuous' ){ echo 'active '; } ?>btn btn-primary waitingUiBut" id="but4" name="s" value="continuous"action="pumpCat">CONTINUOUS</button>  
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `action="?pType="` seems to set the default value properly
But, there is no `'href'` attribute in a button. Try using an  element with proper href and use that to submit the form.

Comment: Take a look at my edits, the toggle buttons now work as intended and perform the correct query.
However when I first vist the page the query string is blank testsite.com/page.php? where I would like testsite.com/page.php?p=XYZ to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goals correctly, I would rethink your apps structure.

You mention you want to use AJAX, so I'd have my SQL query in a separate PHP file, then post the click or slider function value to that file using jQuery, something like:

[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Then update your main HTML file with the returned values.

There is a basic example:

[PHP MySQL AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)